# How can I determine which regular expressions from a list possibly overlap

Tags: mysql, regex, perl

I have a table of regular expressions that are in an MySQL table that I match text against.

Is there a way, using MySQL or any other language (preferably Perl) that I can take this list of expressions and determine which of them MAY overlap.  This should be independent of whatever text may be supplied to the expressions.

All of the expression have anchors.

Here is an example of what I am trying to get:

Expressions:

```
^a$
^b$
^ab
^b.*c
^batch
^catch
```

Result:
`'^b.*c' and '^batch' MAY overlap`

Thoughts?

Thanks,
Scott

Further explanation:

I have a list of user-created regexes and an imported list of strings that are to be matched against the regexes.  In this case the strings are "clean" data (ie they are not user-created but imported from another source - they must not change).

When a user adds to the list of regexes I do not want any collisions on either the existing list of strings nor any future strings (which can not be guessed ahead of time - the only constraints being they are ASCII printable characters no longer than 255 characters).

A brute-force method would be to create a "rainbow" table of all of the permutations of strings and each time a regex is added run all of the regexes against the rainbow table.  However I'd like to avoid this (I'm not even sure of the cost) and so was wondering aloud as to the possibility of an algorithm that would AT LEAST show which regexes in a list MAY collide.

Comment: By "_may overlap_" you mean to say that `^b.*c` and `^\w+` and `^b.+` all match `batch` (so they "overlap" for that string)? If you have _severe_ restrictions on what patterns your regex use then please spell them out here (exhaustively), otherwise the question seems equivalent to reverse engineering the regex engine.

Comment: `^a$` and `^b$` will NEVER match the same string. `^b.*c` and `^\w+` and `^b.+` MAY match, depending on the supplied string (yes, for example `batch`).  I'd like to know if there's a simple way of determining if two regexs MAY match.  And no, I'd rather not brute force it :)

Comment: Alright, thanks for clarification.  Then you want to reverse engineer the engine (more or less).  How can one tell programmatically whether `^\w+` and `^b` can match a string, same string? The program would have to analyze the regex in the given list, so to play the engine, and then conjure a _possibility_ for a string matched by any overlap of those regex in the list. Kinda lot to ask of a program, it seems.

Comment: Well, I think that one can't "_brute force it_"  --- can't come up with a test-list of strings (to run all regex against and see whether any overlap, I presume is what you mean) ... that will (somehow?) exhaust all possibilities for a string that may come up for real. Can't miss _any_, right?

Comment: But, if you have a dirt-poor set of features in that regex list (and  perhaps if the list isn't overly long?), then there may be a practically satisfactory solution.  That would be tailored to that specific regex list (with its feature list).

Comment: There is a limit to the strings that could be thrown at the regexs - the column of strings in my MySQL database.  Each time a string is added I could automate a check of the string against the regexs and count the matches (>1 being a regex "collision").  A stored procedure might do the trick.  It scales linearly with the number of regexs which is fine. This is brute-force-ish with limits.  What I was hoping to avoid with the original question was making the regex validation independent of the possible strings on which to match.

Comment: Ah, that's indeed a viable "brute-force-ish" method. (Doesn't sound too bad at all btw)  I don't see how I can pick two regex (which, say, happen to be `^\w+` and `^b`) and decide that they can, indeed, both match ... what? "Any-word" and "Word-starting-with-given-char" ... categories ... ? How do I even state that?  (And that's on top of "mapping" all possible patterns so that my program knows what they mean and do.) It's an interesting problem, not only "encoding" what possible patterns mean, but also classifying what they _could_ match.  (My $.02 though, perhaps it's not that bad.)

Comment: AFAIK, deciding on equivalence of two regular expressions is p-hard, deciding if two regular expressions overlap is np-hard. Depending on what you want to do, brute force might be a good alternative (since you probably have a good idea what kind of strings you are using this for, it might be possible to prepare a decent test list). And/or you might want to elaborate on your use case, maybe there is a different way to achieve your goal/formulate your problem. Or you might want to ask on https://cs.stackexchange.com for algorithm ideas/complexity considerations.

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you clarify the limitations (other than having an anchor) to the REGEXP, if any. For certain classes of regexp (especially, those which can be represented as wild-cards), matching might be possible using a single pass. In the example above, all REGEXP can be convered to wild-cards.

Comment: @AlexandrEvstigneev I've expanded in the OP (not enough room in a comment).

Comment: "_When a user adds to the list of regexes_" --- no restrictions at all (other than mentioned anchors)? So I add some crazy regex with lookarounds and branches and whatnot ... and the program needs to figure out that it cannot possibly match a string same as what another nasty regex matches?  I think you can only check explicitly for strings you have, so "brute-force" it

Comment: @zdim The expressions would be limited to those that MySQL support, which I believe are BREs.  Even if that assumption is incorrect, it seems that even constrained to BREs the answer to my question is to use brute force.

Comment: Who's regexp engine?  MySQL's (before 8.0) is rather limited.  Perl, PHP, and MySQL 8.0 are at least close to the same.

Comment: By "have an anchor", you mean a _start_ anchor (`^`)?

Comment: Might the regexps include backtracking, etc, things?  `(?=`, etc.  Those add a nasty dimension to the puzzle.  What kinds of char classes?  `[[.alpha.]]`?  `\w`?  What about UTF-8 support?

Answer (score 0):

I will punt on full REs.  Even limiting to BREs and/or MySQL-pre-8.0 will be challenging.  Here are some thoughts.

- If end-anchored and no `+` or `*`, the calculate the length.  The fixed-length can be used as a discriminator.  Also, it could be used for toning back the "brute force" by perhaps an order of magnitude.
- Anything followed by `+` or `*` gets turned into `.*` for simplicity.  (Re the "may collide" rule.)
- Any RE with explicit characters (including those followed by `+`) becomes a discriminator in some situations.  Eg, `^a.*b$` vs `^a.*c$`.
- For those anchored at the end, reverse the pattern and test it that way.  (I don't know how difficult reversing is.)
- If you can say that a particular character must be at any position, then use it as a discriminator:  `^a.b.*c$` -- `a` in pos 1; `b` in pos 3; `c` at end.  Perhaps this can be extended to character classes:  `^\w` may match, but `^\d` and `^a.*\d$` can't.